# US graduate school: expected proficiency and competency in the area of specialization at the beginning of the program

Tags: graduate-school, united-states, computer-science

I am interested in applying to graduate schools in the US in a certain sub-area of computer sciences. However, most of my educational background is in engineering (BS+MS in systems engineering from a good university in Europe). While I have some research experience in the specific research sub-area that I am interested in pursuing, I feel that I may lack some of the more general knowledge that would normally be expected from a computer science graduate.

AFAIK, in the US, any Ph.D. student is expected to read courses for the first 1-2 years. This structure seems ideal for me, as it will allow me to convert my slightly inconsistent self-gained knowledge into something coherent. However, I have two questions:

1. Is it socially acceptable to be spending a significant amount of time during the first 1-2 years of the Ph.D. doing courses and, generally, exploring the subject widely (e.g. in Europe the perception is usually very negative: not dedicating all of one's time to research is often seen as a waste of resources and can result in negative consequences for one's career)?. If I am to also act as a TA + doing graduate courses, I doubt that I will be able to dedicate a significant amount of time to research.
2. Should I make it reasonably apparent in my applications (in the personal statement) that "I am interested in studying such and such subjects in-depth and I am pleased that the department XYZ provides a unique opportunity to do so". The reasoning behind it is that I do not wish to be perceived more competent than I am in the broad area of computer science. Thus, if I get accepted, I should not be expected to become a publication-production-device from day 1 of the program (not to say that I do not intend to publish, and I have published before).

---

If it is relevant, I am not aiming very high from the perspective of the rankings, while having a very good GPA in BS/MS, a very good quant GRE, some research experience, some semi-relevant work experience and at least one reasonably relevant first-author publication (possibly and hopefully two). Nonetheless, I was not very successful professionally, as I could never leave the "obscure start-up environment" with periods of unemployment.

---

I know that there is quite a number of similar questions on the website, but I could not find any questions identical to the ones that I am asking. Please do note that the question is not about the admission chances and hardly about the admission process. I am interested in what are the general expectations from the Ph.D. students with regard to the ratio of the time spent doing coursework/teaching/research during the first 1-2 years of a Ph.D. program in the US.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will vary widely from program to program (so much so that this question is borderline "off topic" in this forum), so your best bet would be to discuss this with members of the department where you are thinking of applying (even/especially students). Still, some thoughts...

> I feel that I may lack some of the more general knowledge that would normally be expected from a computer science graduate

My biggest concern is your skills in analytical math (i.e., writing proofs). If you are starting from zero and expected to take difficult classes in theoretical computer science, this could be difficult. If your gaps are elsewhere (or such courses are not required by your program), it may be easier to fill these gaps through self-study.

> Is it socially acceptable to be spending a significant amount of time during the first 1-2 years of the Ph.D. doing courses and, generally, exploring the subject widely?

In my experience, these classes are **very** difficult, so it is socially acceptable to spend every waking moment trying desperately to pass. Research is for later years. Of course, this will vary school to school.

> Should I make it reasonably apparent in my applications (in the personal statement) that "I am interested in studying such and such subjects in-depth and I am pleased that the department XYZ provides a unique opportunity to do so".

Well, your application to a CS PhD program makes it reasonably apparent that you want to study the subjects in detail, and your application to department XYZ makes it clear that you approve of XYZ's program. So, I'm not sure what this sentence buys you. It's also unclear what you find to be "unique" (i.e., one-of-a-kind) about this particular program; offering courses in CS does not make a CS department unique.

> The reasoning behind it is that I do not wish to be perceived more competent than I am in the broad area of computer science.

I didn't get this at all from your quote. If this is what you want to communicate, I would phrase it as: "I do not wish to be perceived more competent than I am in the broad area of computer science."

Snarking about the language aside, I would suggest that you omit this from your application. Attempting to give a balanced picture of your strengths and weaknesses is perhaps a good idea, but recall that your goal during the application is to sell the program on you. If you yourself have doubts about your ability to be successful in the program, it is better to resolve these outside of the application process (i.e., either before applying, or after being admitted).

> I am interested in what are the general expectations from the Ph.D. students with regard to the ratio of the time spent doing coursework/teaching/research

Again, this will vary from program to program, but as a general guideline, I would say 80% courses, 20% teaching, 0% research for the first year, leading to 100% research by the end.

Comment: Thank you. I find your answer to be reasonably objective and would upvote if I had enough reputation. My primary concern was whether you are expected to know the graduate courses by heart before you start, i.e. whether the social perception is that they exist to allow you to prove what you already know, and you would be looked down upon as an incompetent fool if you ever open lecture notes for a graduate course in the Ph.D. office and start revising :). In any case, I have seen lecture notes/syllabi for typical graduate CS courses, so I have a good idea about the typical content covered.

Answer (score 0):

My general read of your situation is that you're in fine shape. I'm a PhD student at a US institution who also switched fields between undergrad and grad school. I went from a physics BS to electrical engineering PhD and felt like the learning curve of jumping into a new field was very manageable, though of course the steepness of that curve depends on your background. Though I bet you have some decent familiarity with CS if you're pursuing a PhD in it.

To answer your questions:

1. It depends on what you mean by 'explore widely'. Depending on the program, you'll most likely be expected to start on research in some form your first year, but most of your time will still be dedicated to classes. In this sense, you will be able to explore the field without being preoccupied by research. However, all of your classes will be at the graduate level, so you won't be able to take an intro/mid level course (which is what I'd consider widely exploring the field) and have it count towards your degree. You can chose to audit other courses at any level, but this wouldn't count towards your degree and, due to time constraints, is probably not practical until you've finished your required courses. Dedicating ~50% of your time to classes instead of research will not be abnormal and will not hurt your career as long as you communicate with your research advisor and meet his/her expectations.
2. I don't think you need to say so. It would be unusual for your advisor to expect a publication your first year. If you want to take a lot of classes so you can build more breadth in your CS background, you could look for programs that have higher course requirements (some tend to be done within a year or two, others can be closer to three years of class work).

And the specifics of the time split between coursework, teaching, and research depends heavily on the program you're in, your advisor, and the class you're a teaching assistant for. But to answer your question, I think during your first and second years classes will get about 60% of your time.

Lastly, I don't think you need to write anything in your application to the effect of "I want to take courses to patch any holes in my background". For one thing, everyone feels that way to an extent. And any unresolved concerns you have about timing or research requirements would be excellent questions for grad students in the program you're applying to or your potential research advisor. You can also ask how people with different backgrounds tend to do in your program (I was surprised to learn that about a third of the people in my program don't have EE backgrounds, so you'll most likely have company).

Comment: This is helpful, although I would say that moving from physics to EE is a lateral move at the most, whereas moving from an engineering discipline to computer science is a lateral move at the least. 50% of the time is something I could probably live with. My primary concern was outlined explicitly in the comment to cag51's answer: it was about whether or not you are expected to 'know it all' before you start.